# How to call a Javascript function upon the selection of an inplace with editor in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I have an inplace component in PrimeFaces:

```
<p:inplace editor="true">   
 <p:inputTextarea value="#{fieldsElem.path}" style="font-size: 12px; width:80%" />
</p:inplace>
```

Can I call a Javascript function when the user clicks on the inplace?
Or is there an ajax event I can use that will fire when the user selects the inplace?

Thanks much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a binding to the component itself through JQuery like this:

```
<h:head>
   <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#basic").on('click', function(){
            alert('here'); //whatever call you like here
        });
    });
   </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<p:inplace id="basic">
    <p:inputText value="Edit Me" />
</p:inplace>
</h:body>
```